# How to get Vault secret through Terraform?

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I have created the key/secret pair using the Vault UI.

How do I get the secret from Vault through Terraform?

Answer (score 6):

You need to define a vault provider, and fetch it as a data object. Here's a simple example:

```
provider "vault" {
  address = "https://my-vault-address.com"
  skip_tls_verify = true
  token = "xxx"
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "my_secret" {
  path = "secret/path/to/mysecret"
}
```

Then in order to use it:

```
...
pass = data.vault_generic_secret.my_secret.data["password"]
...
```

Comment: Is there any other to get Vault Secret. We are expecting the other way since the token is visible in Terraform file or config.

Comment: Not really, the docs states the secret will be in plain text so treat it as sensitive data - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/generic_secret

Comment: My team suggesting to use GCP Authentication for this.

Comment: Is there any way for GCP Auth like below -

provider "vault" {
  address = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
  auth_login {
    path = "auth/aws/login"
    method = "aws"
    parameters = {
      role = "dev-role-iam"
    }
  }
}